# Javascript - meaning of "parent.parent.someFunction();"

Tags: javascript, html

In a webapplication I came across, there is a javascript line in logout.jsp as:

```
parent.parent.renderProcessingTextOff();
```

On debugging the page with IE script debugger, it is breaking on above line with error as:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

What is the meaning of this error? 
How to solve it?

I am new to javascript, so please explain in simple terms.

Flow of logout is:

on click of logout button, a command is passed and intercepted in interceptor, which directs it to appropriate processor, which forwards the request to logout.jsp.

Its a spring application, if that information is of any help.

Thanks for reading!!

Comment: Looks to me that `parent` is a DOMElement, `parent.parent` is the parent DOMEelement of that DOMElement. The method `.renderProcessingTextOff()` is not a standard DOMElement method, ergo it does not exist and will throw that Exception. So somewhere code is needed to add that method to that specific DOMElement.

Comment: Why is this tagged "spring" and "jsp"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there frames or iframes on your page? Or object elements?

`parent` is a property of the `window` object (and the `window.` part of `window.parent` is assumed if you leave it out).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent):

> When a window is loaded in an `<iframe>`, `<object>`, or `<frame>`, its parent is the window with the element embedding the window.

So if from an iframe that is at least two levels down, the line `parent.parent.renderProcessingTextOff();` says to call the `renderProcessingTextOff()` function defined by its grandparent.

Obviously if that line of code appeared where there wasn't a grandparent with that function defined then you'll get the error you quoted.

Comment: The line is part of logout.jsp and will execute everytime logout.jsp is loaded. Now logout.jsp is getting loaded through servlet dispatcher. So do not know the purpose of this line here. Where does the concept of parent, grandparent, etc. come ??? Sorry, but am new to javascript and its some old code I need to improve.. From your answer, I feel the line is not required at all.. correct ?

Comment: I have no way of knowing if that line is required because I don't know what your `renderProcessingTextOff()` function does. Don't worry about the servlet dispatcher, that's what's happening on your webserver. On the client, in the web browser, is logout.jsp loading such that it fills the whole browser window, or is in an iframe so that it only takes up part of another page? If the latter, the "parent" is the other page.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it looks like the first word, `parent` is an object instance. That object has a property called `parent`, and to access it you use the syntax `parent.parent`. The property is in turn another object, which is supposed to have a property called `renderProcessingTextOff` which is called as a function.

If I would venture to guess about your problem, it seems that `parent.parent` is of the top level `Object` class, and `Object` does not have that method.

If you already is using the IE script debugger, put a breakpoint at that line and examine the `parent` and `parent.parent` objects.

Comment: While this makes sense in general, this answer is incomplete in the context of javascript and the browser environment. "parent" is a pre-defined property on the "window" object, thus implicitly available in the global scope. "parent" refers to the parent "window" in the case of embedded contexts (iframe, frame etc).